# Changing rotation speed of a DIV not working in IE 11, using JS to update CSS animation properties

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to change the rotation speed of a DIV using simple buttons. It works in Chrome, but not IE. Is this a limitation of IE?

```js
var speed = 3;
document.getElementById("speedText").innerHTML = speed + "s";

function changeSpeed(change) {
  speed = speed + change;
  document.getElementById("speedText").innerHTML = speed + "s";
  document.getElementById("rotationDiv").style.animationDuration = speed + "s";
  $("#rotationDiv").load(location.href + " #rotationDiv");
}
```

```css
#rotationDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rotationDiv"></div>
<p id="speedText"></p>
<button id="button1" onclick="changeSpeed(-1)">Speed Up</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="changeSpeed(1)">Slow Down</button>
```

Comment: Very strange. If I do an "Inspect element" after clicking the buttons, the DOM explorer source does say `style="animation-duration: 8s"` in the element, so it has done everything that was expected of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to remove and re-add the animation to get it to pick up the changes.

After changing the speed, change the `animation-name` to a something else, then in a `setTimeout`, set `animation-name` back.  It's a bit of a hack, but it does the trick.

```js
var speed = 3;
document.getElementById("speedText").innerHTML = speed + "s";

function changeSpeed(change) {
  speed = speed + change;
  document.getElementById("speedText").innerHTML = speed + "s";
  document.getElementById("rotationDiv").style.animationDuration = speed + "s";
  document.getElementById("rotationDiv").style.animationName = "x";
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("rotationDiv").style.animationName = "";
  },0);
  $("#rotationDiv").load(location.href + " #rotationDiv");
}
```

```css
#rotationDiv {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1" onclick="changeSpeed(-1)">Speed Up</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="changeSpeed(1)">Slow Down</button>
<p id="speedText"></p>
<div id="rotationDiv"></div>
```

Comment: That worked, and it is indeed very hacky. Any more insight on why we have to do this? Is this just an IE bug?

Comment: My observation is that IE doesn't like changing running animations.  If you remove the animation and re-add it, you are rebuilding the animation from scratch.

Comment: Am using same code for my function, it's working fine Except in IE > 10 speed increasing but not decreasing.   If I do an "Inspect element"  style changing correctly.
@gilly3 i just posted my problem 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254320/changing-slide-speed-of-a-image-not-working-properly-in-ie-11-using-js-to-updat

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue! My use case only required two different animation durations, so I just made two identical sets of keyframes with different names and switched between them. Seems less hacky than timeouts. :)