# Changing Slide speed of a Image not working properly in IE 11, using JS to update CSS animation properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

**This function is used to control pulse speed animation, it's working on all the browsers except in IE 11 and Edge(windows 10)  the pulse speed not decreasing properly. **

*The styles are changing dynamically using javascript but the effects of the style changes are not reflecting in the pulse speed animation for IE 11 and Edge browser.*

```js
function getPulseSpeed(param){
   var speed= 3.5;
   var element = document.getElementById("slideright");
      var style = element.style;
   style.webkitAnimationPlayState = style.mozAnimationPlayState = style.oAnimationPlayState = style.animationPlayState = "paused";
  if(param == 0){
  speed = 3.5;
  style.webkitAnimationDuration = style.mozAnimationDuration = style.oAnimationDuration = style.animationDuration = speed + "s";
  style.animationName = "x";  
   }if(param == 1){
  speed = 2.5;
  style.webkitAnimationDuration = style.mozAnimationDuration = style.oAnimationDuration = style.animationDuration = speed + "s";
  style.animationName = "x";
   } if(param == 2){
  speed = 1.5;
  style.webkitAnimationDuration = style.mozAnimationDuration = style.oAnimationDuration = style.animationDuration = speed + "s";
  style.animationName = "x";  
   } if(param ==3){
  speed = 1;
  style.webkitAnimationDuration = style.mozAnimationDuration = style.oAnimationDuration = style.animationDuration = speed + "s";
  style.animationName = "x";  
   } if(param >=4){
  speed = 0.5;
  style.webkitAnimationDuration = style.mozAnimationDuration = style.oAnimationDuration = style.animationDuration = speed + "s";
   } 
  setTimeout(function(){
   style.animationName = "";
  },0);
  style.webkitAnimationPlayState = style.mozAnimationPlayState = style.oAnimationPlayState = style.animationPlayState = "running";   
  }
```

```css
.slide-right{
 z-index: 2;
    width: 125px;
    height: 71px;
    background-image: url(https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-4fU00NOK5pw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACU/43A4OiCAbGI/photo.jpg?sz=125);
    /* -webkit-animation: slide 2s linear infinite;
    animation: slide 2s linear infinite; */
 animation-name: slide;
 animation-duration: 3.5s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    animation-play-state: running;
    left: 45px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    from {
       background-position: 0 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position: -125px 0;
    }
}

@keyframes slide {
    from {
       background-position: 0 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position: -125px 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="slideright" class="asset-hide screen_line asset-display slide-right">
    </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  In your code snippet, `getPulseSpeed()` is never called.  When I run your code snippet in Chrome and in Edge, there is no noticeable difference.

Comment: Actually am calling this `getPulseSpeed()` on mouse move, here am used snippet for formatting my code. Thanks @gilly3.
I solved my problem by creating different DIV that content different  animation. Am just doing show hide based on condition.